# How to check whether checkbox is checked or unchecked using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
 <div  ng-repeat="sub in rolem.submenus" >
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="hasChecked" ng-change="Menu_Dtls_Checkbox(sub)"/>{{sub}} <br/>
</div>
```

And Controller is,

```
   $scope.Menu_Dtls_Checkbox=function(submenuname){
       if($scope.hasChecked){
           alert("checked");
       }
       else
       alert("Unchecked");
```

But is it not working .Please give solution.

Comment: Does your `ng-repeat` works?

Comment: Does the function `Menu_Dtls_Checkbox` invokes?

Comment: Yes.ng-repeat is working fine.Even Menu_Dtls_Checkbox function alse invecked.$scope.hasChecked is getting undefined.

Comment: Did you checked the answer?

Comment: In ng-repeat ng-model will create new scope on every element loop through. You need to check individual scope. My suggestion use function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass hasChanged flag as a parameter to your function:

```
<div  ng-repeat="sub in rolem.submenus" >
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="hasChecked" ng-change="Menu_Dtls_Checkbox(sub, hasChecked)"/>{{sub}} <br/>
</div> 


$scope.Menu_Dtls_Checkbox=function(submenuname, hasChecked){
   if(hasChecked){
       alert("checked");
   }
   else{
     alert("Unchecked");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you have `checkbox` inside the `ng-repeat`. The `ng-repeat` will create a new `ng-model` for each `checkbox` created. So, i suggest you to use a JSON object to track the value of the checkbox like below.

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.rolem = {
       submenus:['xxx','yyy','zzz']
  };
  $scope.cbList = {};
  $scope.Menu_Dtls_Checkbox=function(submenuname){
    if($scope.cbList[submenuname]){
      alert("checked");
    }
    else{
     alert("Unchecked");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
 <div  ng-repeat="sub in rolem.submenus" >
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cbList[sub]" ng-change="Menu_Dtls_Checkbox(sub)"/>{{sub}} <br/>
   </div>
</div>
```